# Sending messages in XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, xmppframework

I'm not getting any errors, so when I build it out to the iOS simulator nothing happens. I don't see any keyboard pop-up to type or any information in the console. It's just nothing. Why can't I send any messages? Thanks.

Here is my code that is in the RootViewController.m

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#pragma mark Sending
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

-(void)sendMessage
{
    NSString *messageStr =messageField.text;

    if([messageStr length] > 0)
    {   
        NSLog(@"Message sending from my iphone");
        NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
        [body setStringValue:messageStr];
        NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"chat"];
        [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"destination address"];
        [message addChild:body];
        NSLog(@"message1%@",message);

        [[self appDelegate].xmppStream sendElement:message];
    } 
}
```

And here is my code in the RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
{
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
    UITextField *messageField;
}

- (IBAction)settings:(id)sender;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To launch your keyboard:

```
[self.messageField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Your message sending logic is partially correct, modify your "to" attribute's string value to a user's JID string:

```
[message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:@"_recipientJID"];
```